# angular2 how to change input variable dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

If the question is not properly setup with right word sorry for that, I'll hope I could make you clear what I mean by showing you this:

```
<sebm-google-map-marker 
             *ngFor="let clustermarker of clusters" 
             (markerClick)="clustermarkerClicked()" 
             [latitude]="clustermarker.latitude" 
             [longitude]="clustermarker.longitude" 
             [iconUrl]="clustermarker.icon" 
             [visible]="true">
</sebm-google-map-marker>
```

As you see I have an input visible in the marker tag, and I have a zoomChange event on my google map named:

```
testFunction(e){
  console.log(e);

  if ( e === 17 || e === 18) {
   Here I want to set the variable of visible to false
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<sebm-google-map-marker 
             *ngFor="let clustermarker of clusters" 
             (markerClick)="clustermarkerClicked()" 
             [latitude]="clustermarker.latitude" 
             [longitude]="clustermarker.longitude" 
             [iconUrl]="clustermarker.icon" 
             [visible]="isVisible">
</sebm-google-map-marker>
```

```
isVisible:boolean = false;
testFunction(e){
  console.log(e);

  if ( e === 17 || e === 18) {
   this.isVisible = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much forget that I could use an variable -.-"